# Stop screen-lock and user-logout and Bluetooth disconnections when closing MacBook's lid in Ventura

Tags: screen-lock, ventura, macbook-pro

The MacOS Ventura release has been changed in the way the options are organized in System Settings/Preferences.

My question is, how to **prevent the computer/screen lock** and/or **prevent automatic the user logout** when closing the lid of the MacBook Pro.
I was able to reach this goal with the use of the "*Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off*" in the 'Lock Screen' panel in System Settings, but it feels like an indirect workaround and not the exact definition designed for what I am looking for.

In addition, even after using the aforementioned switch select box (i.e., selecting 'Never' for it, to prevent locking) - still the programs are stopping to run as soon as I cover the lid. For example, the AirPods disconnect and music stop playing.

Is there a generic, direct way to neutralize the locking and logging-out when closing the lid, making the lid just a physical cover, without any affect on the system software?